# Program to view webcam on login/lock screen?

Tags: windows-7, webcam, lockscreen

Is there a program to show the (built-in) camera on the login or lock screen of Windows 7?

It doesn't need to do anything else, no face detection, just be able to view the camera.

Requirements:

- runs on Windows 7 64 bit
- <£10 or preferably free
- uses the built in webcam
- video is as big as possible (preferably full-screen)

If possible, open source, but not necessarily :)

Comment: Are you using this to stop people from touching your laptop when you are going to the toilet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could recommend two applications which fits with your requirements really close but unfortunately these both the software's does this whole face detection part :(

- Freeware application [LemonScreen](https://www.keylemon.com/) it adds face recognition to your Windows login screen, allowing you to login to your locked PC by simply sitting down in front of your computer,for any additional features that you want you need to obtain the licence
- Freeware application [BananaScreen](https://bananascreen.jaleco.com/) adds face recognition login to your webcam-enabled Windows computer,used as a Security software that allows users to unlock their computer via facial recognition.

Comment: is there an option to not use the recognition part? and is the video fullscreen?

Comment: unfortunately no... both these software's are Designed for Authentication,and nope its not full-screen video

Comment: Oh well... I guess these will be my last resort :)

Comment: I did say last resort... :)